# Type Mismatch Error in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VLookUp functionality in VBA.
And getting error while records are returned from VLookup.
Values in excel is alphanumeric

Below is my code---

```
Sub SKUMISMATCH()

    Dim Wms_Row As Variant
    Dim Wms_Col As Variant

    Table1 = Sheet1.Range("A2:A243293")
    Table2 = Sheet1.Range("J2:K295445")

    Wms_Row = Sheet1.Range("G2").Row
    Wms_Col = Sheet1.Range("G2").Column

    For Each c1 In Table1
        Sheet1.Cells(Wms_Row, Wms_Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c1, Table2, 2, False)
        Wms_Row = Wms_Row + 1
    Next c1

    MsgBox "VLookup Complete"

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: A few issues off the top (which were more noticeable after properly indenting your code)...  You have variable that are not declared.  Add the line `Option Explicit` to the top of [every] module [always] to help identify declaration problems.  (See [mcve])

Comment: Next: how many loops do you think your `For Each...Next` statement will have to do?  Do you think that's necessary?  Third: You're getting an error?  What? Where? What have you tried?  What are you trying to do? and Why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you provide. To help us help you, I suggest you check the Help pages for [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and, most importantly, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Let me try to explain more clearly. I am getting error at, Sheet1.Cells(Wms_Row, Wms_Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c1, Table2, 2, False). After performing VLookUp i am trying to include the value in col G.

Comment: As I wrote, I cannot reproduce your error with the information you have provided.  The only error I get is `Application-defined or object-defined error` when the function does not find a match.  I do not get a `Type Mismatch` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. You might want to look at ways of further optimizing to make code run faster.

```
Option Explicit   'Always use

Public Sub SKUMISMATCH()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False   'optimise code
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim Wms_Row As Long 'Declare with expected type not variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Const Wms_Col As Long = 7 'declare as constant as doesn't change value

    Wms_Row = 2
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Table1 As Range 'Declare all variables
    Dim Table2 As Range
    Dim c1 As Range

    With ws 'use With statement to speed up code

        Set Table1 = .Range("A2:A243293") 'set range variables
        Set Table2 = .Range("J2:K295445")
        Table1.Offset(, 6).ClearContents   'Clear lookup return area in case changes to lookup range alters where errors may occur.

        For Each c1 In Table1

            On Error Resume Next 'skip non matches
               .Cells(Wms_Row, Wms_Col) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c1, Table2, 2, False)
            On Error GoTo 0

            Wms_Row = Wms_Row + 1

        Next c1

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

    MsgBox "VLookup Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes i need to optimize the code. Thanks for the inputs. I am working on excel with 250 k records and currently once i run the vba script, excel sheet freezes.

Comment: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/2/25/best-way-to-improve-vba-macro-performance-and-prevent-slow-code-execution

Comment: Thank You for your help, the suggestions worked. I had to modify my code a bit